# jQuery: drag/drop images inside div's with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to use the jquery drag and drop in my web application and drag and drop images in different div's with the same *Class*.

But when I drag and drop the images onto one of the Div's, it will copy the same image into other div's with the same class as well!

**I have created a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7nwhs3my/

and this is my entire code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({

        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit',
        stack: '.drag',
        revert: "invalid"


    });

            $(".droppable").droppable({



                    drop: function (e, ui) {

                    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();
                        ui.helper.remove();




                    x.draggable({

                        //helper: 'original',
                        containment: '.droppable',
                        tolerance: 'fit',
                        stack: '.drag'



                    });

                    x.resizable({

                      animate: true,
                      //aspectRatio: 16 / 9,

                      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                      handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"

                    });
                    x.appendTo('.droppable');
                    $("#tools").show();
                    $("#logo").hide();
                    $("#thumbs").show();

                }

                }

            });


});
```

I also tried to use something like this:

```
$(".droppable").this.droppable({
```

or this:

```
$(".droppable").droppable[0]({
```

but I don't think I am approaching it correctly because they stop my entire code functioning.

any advise/help would be appreciated.

Edit:

I've added this: `$(ui.draggable).appendTo( this );` to my code but this will remove stop the images from being drag-able after they have been dropped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, Hopefully it's more what you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({

        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit',
        stack: '.drag',
        revert: "invalid"


    });

            $(".droppable").droppable({

                    drop: function (e, ui) {
                        x = ui.helper.clone().css({position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0});
                        ui.helper.remove();

                        x.draggable({

                        //helper: 'original',
                        containment: $(this).closest('droppable'),
                        tolerance: 'fit',
                        stack: '.drag'



                    });

                    x.resizable({

                      animate: true,
                      //aspectRatio: 16 / 9,

                      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                      handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"

                    });
                    x.appendTo($(this));
                    $("#tools").show();
                    $("#logo").hide();
                    $("#thumbs").show();

                }



            });


});
```

Comment: this works only on 1 of the divs! so I cannot drop the images onto any other divs.

Comment: To clarify are you wanting to drag the image into one dive and then be able to drag it from there to the next div?  I assumed you just wanted to drag the image onto a div with the droppable class

Comment: No, I need to drag the image into one div and keep it there! I don't want to drag it from there into any other Div's.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully get closer to what you were looking for